# Can I have HTTP URLs in openid-configuration when requested by pods in the same Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, openshift, identityserver4

I have a Kubernetes cluster (OpenShift) that hosts a front-end, an Identity service and several application services. The Identity server uses IdentityServer4, and can be contacted by the client or by a pod in the cluster. Pods in the cluster, including Identity, only expose an HTTP port, leaving all the HTTPS management to the ingresses.

This is a problem when ApplicationA tries to contact Identity, because it sends a request for `https://identity.yyy.svc.cluster.local/path`, but Identity does not listen for HTTPS traffic and so the request times out. The thing is that ApplicationA is configured to contact Identity with an `http://` URL, and that's what it uses to get `/.well-known/openid-configuration`, but then that file contains HTTPS URLs.

Since `openid-configuration` is dynamically generated (as shown by the fact that the URL authority is the same as that of the request), is it possible to make it expose HTTP URLs for certain requests (those coming from `*.cluster.local`)? Or do I need to setup the cluster in a different way?

**EDIT** Clarification

This is what I get when I hit `http://identity.yyy.svc.cluster.local/.well-known/openid-configuration` (prettified for readability):

```
{
"issuer":"https://identity.yyy.svc.cluster.local",
"jwks_uri":"https://identity.yyy.svc.cluster.local/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks",
"authorization_endpoint":"https://identity.yyy.svc.cluster.local/connect/authorize",
"token_endpoint":"https://identity.yyy.svc.cluster.local/connect/token",
"userinfo_endpoint":"https://identity.yyy.svc.cluster.local/connect/userinfo",
[omitted]
}
```

These URLs are dynamic:

- if the request is for `https://example.com/Identity/.well-known/openid-configuration`, then the URLs look like `https://example.com/Identity/<path>`;
- if the request is for `http://identity.yyy.svc.cluster.local/.well-known/openid-configuration`, then the URLs look like `https://identity.yyy.svc.cluster.local/<path>`.

I would like that the scheme also reflect the request, just as the host does. I would expect this to be a change that must be done in Identity, not in each and every application, but I don't know how to do that.

**EDIT** Resolution

I found the problem was caused by a hacky middleware that set every request's scheme to HTTPS. Fixing that, and correctly using and configuring the `UseForwardedHeaders()` middleware, allowed me to get the correct scheme in the discovery document.

Comment: Try to set the IssuerUrl i IdentityServer Server configuration https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/reference/options/#main

Comment: I'm going to try that. However, the docs say "If it is not set (the default), the issuer is inferred from the URL used by clients". But my issuer always end up using HTTPS. Is there a rule that the issuer must be HTTPS? Is this configurable somehow?

Comment: The issuer must use HTTPS between the browser and the issuer; otherwise,  cookies will be blocked. You can't avoid that.  Internally, between clients and issuer on the bckend, you can use HTTP, but the browser must use HTTPS.

Comment: @ToreNestenius Setting the IssuerUri does change the issuer URI in the discovery document, but it doesn't change anything else. Plus, it sets it for ALL requests, so it would still either break usage from inside or from inside the cluster.

Comment: I'm starting to think my only solution is to generate the document myself, basing it on its current auto-generated response. What would be the dangers of doing that?

Comment: No, I wouldn't generate my own; I think you need to separate the inside from the outside.  I haven't dealt with your situtation, so I am not sure what the correct solution would be. One could be to have one public indentityServer and one Internal IdentityServer, using the same singing keys and database.  :-)

Comment: What about a middleware to rewrite the scheme of the URLs after they have been generated by IdentityServer?

Comment: I don't know the optimal and correct question for this.  I have done a lot of IdentityServer work, but not this specific problem.  but I would use the public HTTPS URL  in the document, but internally, call it using the internal address. if the discovery document alone is the issue, then you can always add the signing key manually to both the AddOpenIDConnect and AddJwtBearer.